# Why would git fetch take very long, if i can ping github just well?

Tags: git

The internet connection looks good, 350Mb/s, ping 15ms, i will try git clone and such too, but nothing should have changed from yesterday, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISP was blocking port 22, in UK the default is safe web, and it can be unlocked via account settings. Using VPN also helps.